# mysql and duplicated entry report

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

I use phpmyadmin to manually change the id (auto_increment) of some row data, therefore when I run my program to create a new row data, it returns me an error of "duplicated entry id and thus could not create the row".
This problem seems classical but I don't know the right keywords or phrases to look it up on google. Thank you.

Comment: can you post the schema of your table? or the result of this `DESCRIBE yourtableName`

Comment: do you know a commandline to extract that sort of table description into a text file ? The table described consumes more than the console screen display I can't view completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=X
```

Where X is some number higher than the highest ID.

I haven't tested this, but it may work:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=(SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM tablename)
```

(It may fail due to selecting from the same table that is being altered)

Comment: +1, Its also worth noting that you could also do this through the phpMyAdmin interface by clicking the table then the Operations tab.